# Private access with self-bounded generics

Tags: java, generics, visibility

Combining private field access with the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) in Java seems to tickle a weird edge case in the visibility rules:

```
public abstract class Test<O extends Test<O>> implements Cloneable {
    private int x = 0;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected final O clone() {
        try {
            return (O) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException ex) {
            throw new AssertionError(ex);
        }
    }

    public final int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public final O withX(int x) {
        O created = clone();
        created.x = x;  // Compiler error: The field Test<O>.x is not visible
        return created;
    }
}
```

Simply changing the `withX()` method to this...

```
    public final O withX(int x) {
        O created = clone();
        Test<O> temp = created;
        temp.x = x;
        return created;
    }
```

...makes the code compile. I tested this in Oracle's `javac` and in Eclipse's compiler. What gives?

Comment: Cloneable and clone is filled with WTFs and gotchas in Java.

Comment: @Powerlord As documented in the accepted answer below, this problem has nothing to do with `clone()` specifically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isnt actually an issue with generics.  The [JLS inheritance rules](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.2.1.3) keep private fields from being visible in sub classes.  Because X is private, it is not a member of type `O`, even though it is a member of type `Test<O>` and `O` is a subtype of `Test<O>`.  If you had used code like:

```
public final O withX(int x) {
    Test<O> created = clone();
    created.x = x;
    return (O) created;
}
```

It would work.  This is an instance where LSP is not upheld by Java, but it is only a local problem with the type system, since private fields are only available to objects of the same type.  If it didn't work this way than private fields wouldn't really be private.  I dont think having a special exception to the rules for recursive templates is a good idea.

Note, this is never actually a limitation of what you can do.  You can always cast the subtype up to the the supertype when you want to make the change, just like you do in your alternative code.

Comment: Huh, you're right! Accessing a field in a superclass, declared in the superclass, when you have a variable typed as a subclass is a compile error. Like above, assigning it to a temporary variable with the superclass's type fixes it. That's... rather silly, and not something I do often enough to have noticed up until now.